# Relationship between a matrix and its eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ and  its eigenvalue $λ$ and its eigenvector $\vec{x}$.

Problem:

From the definition that $A\vec{x}=λ\vec{x}$, can I say that eigenvectors $\vec{x}$ must be all in $A$'s column space and thus say that the rank of matrix $A$ must be not less than the number of $A$'s independent eigenvectors?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This stack site is about the technical computing software called Mathematica and the associated Wolfram Language. I believe your question can be more suitably answered at the Mathematics Stack Exchange. I also note that you haven't asked a specific question yet.

Comment: thanks for reminding me

Comment: This is best suited to the math forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct! From $A\vec{x}=λ\vec{x}$ we get $A(\frac1\lambda\vec{x})=\vec{x}$ and thus $\vec x$ is in the column space of $A$ ... unless $\lambda=0$, in which case this argument doesn't work. (Consider $A$ equal to the zero matrix, for example.) However, you can probably recover a valid implication if you consider only eigenvectors with nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: got it ! thanks a lot!!!